# swift UIViewController background set withUIImageView is shown grey overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I'm setting a UIViewController background. When presented the background has a grey(isch) overlay. Please note that I don't use the IB completed app is implemented in pure swift code

images:

left:original stored in Assets.xcassets

right: image as shown by the ViewVontroller

[image]

```
import UIKit

class SignOnVC: UIViewController {

    let background: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()

        //image sits in Assets.xcassets
        image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backgroundScreen") 

        return image
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(background)

        // constraints.....        
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be happening based on the code you have shown. are you adding any other views? there must be something specifically causing this. what type of image is it?

Comment: this is the first vc after the launchscreen. The image is a png image. Any further inputs are welcome.